# Error during Compilation of angular Project

Tags: node.js, angular

while i am trying to compile the angular project in command prompt i am getting the following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F28P.png)

Comment: There is no error message (or command prompt) in the image that you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try @app/post/post-create/post-create.component'

Also a correct image of the build error instead of intilsens error would help.
What version of angular are you using?